# Arrange items in xy-grid depending on their relationship

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, optimization, scipy

I have n items in a `dict`, each of which has an x and a y coordinate:

```
items = {1: {x: 0, y: 0}, 2: {x: 1, y: 0}, ...
```

(The initial coordinates don't matter. The data structure is also just an example - could also be `items = [(0, 0), (1, 0), ...` for example. Whatever works best.)

Additionally, I have a list that contains pairs of item indices to define which items are related to each other:

```
relation = [{1, 2}, {1, 7}, {2, 5}, ...
```

(I'm using `set` instead of `tuple` here to show that the order doesn't matter. The relation is symmetric. But I can use whichever data structure works best.)

I'd like to fill an xy-grid with the items 1, 2, ... n in such a fashion that related items are as close as possible to each other. The coordinates are integers only. And no grid space can be occupied by more than one item.

A useful metric to define "as close as possible" would be the Manhattan metric for example:

```
def manhattan(i, j):
    return abs(items[i]["x"] - items[j]["x"]) + abs(items[i]["y"] - items[j]["y"])
```

Is there an obvious way to do this? Does an algorithm exist for this problem?

Comment: What purpose do the given co-ords have? Assuming these are "preferred" locations for the items, how do you want to trade off between minimising the distance between related items, and positioning items in their preferred locations? Whatever the answer, this problem is almost certainly NP-complete -- if preferred locations are less important, then a reduction from Bandwidth Minimisation will probably suffice to prove this.

Comment: How many items are there? 10? 100? 1000000000?